# paging in C# with back next link

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I want to page on my view with some C# code like

Back 1 2 3 4 5 Next
on click of Next link
my next paging should be shown like 
back 6 7 8 9 10 Next and so on. here is my code
Thanks in advance

```
 int j = 1;
            <div class="pagent">
                <span class="pagetxtpg">
                    @if (Model.PageCount > 1)
            {
                if (Model.PageNumber != 1)
                {
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" onclick="ChangePageToFirst(); return false">
                            First |
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>First |</span>
                }

                if (Model.PageNumber > 1)
                {
                    int k = Model.PageNumber - 1;

                    <span>
                        <a href="#" onclick="ChangePageRecently('@k'); return false">
                            Back
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>Back</span>
                }
                for (j = Model.PageNumber; j <= 4; j++)
                {
                    for (j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
                    {

                        if (Model.PageNumber == j)
                        {
                            <a href="#" class="tab" onclick="ChangePageRecently('@j'); return false">@j</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="#" onclick="ChangePageRecently('@j'); return false">@j</a>
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (Model.PageNumber > 4 && Model.PageNumber < Model.PageCount)
                {
                    for (j = Model.PageNumber; j < Model.PageCount; j++)
                    {
                        <a href="#"  onclick="ChangePageRecently('@j'); return false">
                            @j
                        </a>
                    }
                    int p = Model.PageNumber + 1;
                    <span>
                        <a href="#"  onclick="ChangePageRecently('@p'); return false">
                            Next
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                else if (Model.PageNumber < Model.PageCount)
                {
                    int k = Model.PageNumber + 1;
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" onclick="ChangePageRecently('@k'); return false">

                            Next
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                if (Model.PageCount > Model.PageNumber)
                {
                    <span>
                        <a href="#" onclick="ChangePageRecently('@Model.PageCount'); return false">
                            | Last
                        </a>
                    </span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>| Last </span>
                }
            }
                </span>
            </div>
```

and here is my javascript function to change the page

```
function ChangePageRecently(i) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Counsellor/RecentlyQuestionView/' + i,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                //load returned data inside contentFrame DIV
                $('#RecentAskedQuestionsList').html(result.result);
            }
        });
    }
```

my pagecount is 7, pageNumber is the current page on which I am

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: right now it works like     First | Back 1 2 3 4 5 Next | Last                                       I want when i click on Next it must show First | Back 6 7 8 9 10 Next | Last  and so on, when i click Next it show then 11 12 13 14 15